# Change IIS Site Home Directory w/ Powershell

Tags: iis, powershell

I can query the AD and find all the IIS sites and their virtual directories, now I need to be able to update those home directories and save the changes.

After I fetch the directory entry I can display the site path using `$site.Path`, however setting it doesn't seem to have any effect.  It never changes the actual stored path.

I have tried `$site.Path = <new path>` and `$site.Put( "Path", <new path> )` but neither have these seem to be affecting the stored path.

```
    $site = $iis.psbase.children | 
        where {$_.keyType -eq "iiswebserver"} | 
        where {$_.psbase.properties.servercomment -eq $siteConfig.name };

    $s = [ADSI]($site.psbase.path + "/ROOT");
    $s.Path
    # $s.Path = $siteConfig.path
    # $s.Put("Path", $siteConfig.path )
    $s.psbase.CommitChanges()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I tried this and it seems to work:

```
    $s.psbase.properties.path[0] = $siteConfig.path
    $s.psbase.CommitChanges()
```

Is there a better cleaner way of handling this?

Comment: I don't think so.  There might be a better way with the Quest AD cmdlets (which are free), but to make it cleaner, you could wrap that in a function.

Answer (score 21):

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
Set-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\' -name physicalPath -value $siteConfig.path
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee909471(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Not that this will not move the files. You have to do that in another command.