# Changing Phisycal path via PowerShell for iis

Tags: powershell, iis

I want to change my IIS website physical path according to a variable,
for example $New_Directory contains the directory path and I want to change my physical path to it
thanks
best regards.

Comment: Are you simply trying to switch directory in PowerShell at the prompt or do you want to change the location of the `inetpub` folder? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hello, I just want to change directory of a site in powershell

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5463780/3156906 and see if it helps. Looks like it should work...

Comment: And what's your question about this? What have you tried so far, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try below PowerShell script:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$iisWebsite="C:\s1"
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\MySite -name physicalPath -value $iisWebsite
```

if you want to take input from the user then use this:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$iisWebsite=Read-Host "Please enter your new path"
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\MySite -name physicalPath -value $iisWebsite
```